# Do confidential transactions produce an UTXO

Tags: privacy, utxo, confidential-transactions

There must be magical cryptographic reason why CT doesn't create an UTXO.
If it did make an UTXO, it'd be trivial to calculate the input + output right?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In Confidential Transactions (as used in Blockstream's Elements and Liquid), there are still identifiable UTXOs.

The only change is that instead of the amount, a homomorphic commitment to the amount is stored. While not technically correct, you could see it as a form of encryption that is compatible with addition and subtraction. So if *a+b=c+d* then *E(a)+E(b)=E(c)+E(d)* (where *E()* is the encryption function). This lets the verifiers still ascertain that the amounts in input and outputs match up.